# How to set a relative path/Uri in ResourceDictionary's source

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, prism-4

I am trying to refer to a MergedDictionaries.SharedStyles project which has all Styles that has to be used allover application. So here i have different styles under different folders as Resource Dictionaries. so finally i have Merged them into AllSharedStyles.xaml and have that at Styles project level.

Now I have another ResourceDictionary at Solution level <> which refers to AllSharedStyles.xaml resource dictionary <<>>. This ResourceDictionary is added as a link to all my modules in solution.

Issue here is In my SharedResourceDictionary i am having following MergedDictionaries

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MergedDictionaries.SharedStyles;component/AllSharedStyles.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/View/LocalResource.xaml" /> 
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

[image: Project architecture]

I have refered to common Resource first then my local inorder to override(only if required) any styles specific to module.

Now  when i run the application it complains

```
'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '10'.
```

Thats the error message.

With my understanding it is looking for proper reference. I also tried using Pack URL ref: [Pack URLss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).
Here is the pack url:

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MergedResourceDictionaries.Styles;component/component/AllSharedStyles.xaml" />
```

So any suggestions on How to have a relative path here????

Sorry for my description/projection of problem

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally worked out solution:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="../SharedResourceDictionary.xaml" />
```

Changed it to relative path and given root path.

Comment: Note that this won't work if you include the assembly in another project. You would require an absolute path which, in your case, would be `/Shell.Run;component/SharedResourceDictionary.xaml`

Comment: Using a relative path, `../../../Common/Editing/Controls/ItemTemplates.xaml`, worked for me as well, although VS had suggested an absolute path, `/Common/Editing/Controls/ItemTemplates.xaml`, and the editor was able to resolve it (e.g. when using F12 to do to jump to the file)...